# fixed headers in table, html

Tags: javascript, html

i had an table like this

```
   <div style="overflow:auto">
   <table>
     <thead><tr style="position:fixed"><th></th></tr></thead>
   </table>
   </div>
```

Now my problem is when i scroll div the header(that is tr element) is fixed it works fine but when i scroll the scrollbar of window the header tr is not fixed inside the div. I moves along the scroll bar of the window... Can any one help me to find out the solution please

Comment: 1) What does this have to do with Javascript? 2) Can you show more of your code? I don't get the scrollbar on the div, only on the window, and it works fine. 3) I hadn't expected it to work fine, since table parts don't like things like positioning.

Comment: Thank you for your reply...Actually there is a large data in the div i have to maintain headers fixed and i am using width as percentages like <th style="width:10%"></th> and moreover my window contains so many things so scroll bar appears for my window also... But when i had given position as "fixed" it scrolls with the window. Finally my concern is that i would like to fix the headers in the table.

Comment: Well, with some more fiddling, like adding a fixed height to the div, I did have two scrollbars. And yes, the `tr` does get fixed to the window, not to the `div`. But I think I may have a solution.

Comment: Thank you.. can you please help me to find the solution...

Answer (score 4):

I don't know If I'm getting your question right, but you may find this helpful http://fixedheadertable.com/

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I tried to do it in CSS alone, but that didn't work out, so you do need a bit of Javascript.

```
<div style="overflow:auto; position:relative;"
    onscroll="document.getElementById('fixedtr').style.top = this.scrollTop+'px';">
  <table>
    <thead>
      <tr style="position:absolute; top:0; left:0" id="fixedtr">
        <th>Table header</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
```

See [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/A7pyp/1/).

This is how you want it, right?

Comment: Thank for your reply. I had used this. This has partially fixed my problem. My problem is i had given th element widths in %'s something like <th style="width:10%"</th> so when i scroll down the widths vary.... How to fix this issue...

Comment: Sorry, I can't duplicate this problem. How does the width vary?

Comment: At first after the page load the headers appears in correct width. when once i scroll down the headers adjusts the width as auto i mean when i had column as "SLMG" the th element width is size of SLMG text... but i applied the width for it as 30%...thats my problem

Comment: I can't duplicate the problem you have; can you post a jsFiddle of what you have now, or a link to your site? Hopwever, I do find that not all browsers handle width on the positioned elements the same, so it will need some more work. For a start, try giving both the `<tr>` and the `<th>` in it a width.